# How do I get certain buttons working?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I get a button working?

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.title=title("Test")

button=button(window, text='Increase variable', command=Var)
button.pack()

variable=0
def Var():
    variable=variable+1
```

I get an error saying Var is not defined. If I put the function before the button code I get an error when clicking the button.

```
from tkinter import *

variable=0
def Var():
    variable=variable+1

window=Tk()
window.title=title("Test")

button=button(window, text='Increase variable', command=Var)
button.pack()
```

Clicking on the button will yield an error local variable referenced before assignment. How do I get this to work?

Comment: well, on the 1st example `Var()` is only defined after being used.

Comment: I gave two examples. Both of these don't work. So give me a working example!

Comment: *"give me a working example!"* are you ok?!

Answer (score 1):

If `variable` is a global variable, you need to indicate to `Var` that this is the case.

Comment: Google 'python global'.

Comment: Geez you don't need to down vote just because I don't know something.

Comment: @21harrisont: you are expected to do research before asking such a basic question. I understand you are just learning, but part of learning to program is learning to do research. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)